# Vietoris-Rips complex with repeated vertices

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis, topological-graph-theory

I am trying to study Vietoris-Rips complexes that arise from a point data sample, in the context of topological data analysis. Each data point maps to a point in a metric space by some measurement function, which will serve as a vertex of the Vietoris-Rips complex.

Suppose some $k$ data points in the sample coincide, which means that the corresponding vertices in the VR complex are superimposed/repeated. (These $k$ vertices are at distance $0$ from each other and so form a $(k-1)$-face, which is homotopy equivalent to a point). I would like to know if there is any result which guarantees that a VR complex with such clusters of repeats is homotopy equivalent to a VR complex where each cluster of coincident vertices is just considered as a single vertex.

Any insights will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is known that a VR complex with such clusters of repeats is homotopy equivalent to a VR complex where each cluster of coincident vertices is just considered as a single vertex. Indeed, suppose that $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are $k$ coincident vertices in your dataset. Then as you have pointed out, each $v_i$ and $v_j$ are connected by an edge for $i \neq j$. Also, it is the case that for any other vertex $u$ in the dataset, $u$ is either connected by an edge to all of the $v_i$ or to none of the $v_i$. Therefore, the vertex $v_1$ *dominates* the vertex $v_2$, which means that these two vertices are connected by an edge, and furthermore that every neighbor of $v_2$ is also a neighbor of $v_1$. Therefore, since $v_2$ is dominated, you can remove vertex $v_2$ without changing the homotopy type of the clique complex (the Vietoris-Rips complex). The reason why removing the dominated vertex $v_2$ doesn't change the homotopy type is because the link of the vertex $v_2$ is contractible --- indeed the link of the vertex $v_2$ is a cone (with apex $v_1$). Continuing as such, vertex $v_1$ dominates vertex $v_3$, and so you can remove vertex $v_3$ without changing the homotopy type. At the end, you have removed all of the vertices $v_2,v_3,\ldots,v_k$ without changing the homotopy type, leaving only a single vertex $v_1$ left at this position.

For example papers that give more information on dominated vertices, see the papers *Complexes of graph homomorphisms*, or *Strong homotopy types, nerves and collapses*, or *LC reductions yield isomorphic simplicial complexes*, or *Nerve complexes of circular arcs*, for example.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! The idea of one vertex _dominating_ another vertex is key.